# Question about multiplying summations with another summation inside

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, generating-functions

I have the following:

$$
y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty [x^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)a_{k+1} P_{n-k}] \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n[s_n - \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k+1}(k+1)R_{n-k}]
$$

I can easily multiply

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty [a_n x^n] \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k b_{n-k})
$$
But the summation above i seem to be lacking the intuition to find the outcome of the summation, What is a trick to finding out the result of the summation?

Comment: $$\bar a_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)a_{k+1} P_{n-k}\qquad \bar b_n=s_n - \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k+1}(k+1)R_{n-k}$$

Comment: @Did That seems so easy! thanks